# How to compare two arrays in javascript and remove the similar values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, character

I'm new to javascript and web development.

I am planning to compare two Strings and remove the same elements from the said strings.

for example:

str1 = "john"
str2 = "jane"

str1 and str2 both have "j" and "n", and therefore removed from the string
it's supposed to look like this:
str1Res = "oh"
str2Res = "ae"

this is my code. the problem is:
the firstName variable is correctly processed. However, the secondName doesn't remove anything.

```
    var firstName = "john"
    var secondName = "jane"
    firstName = firstName.toLowerCase();
    secondName = secondName.toLowerCase();

    //remove whitespaces and split to array
    var firstNameArray = firstName.replaceAll(" ", "").split('');
    var secondNameArray = secondName.replaceAll(" ", "").split('');

    var firstNameRes = [];
    var secondNameRes = [];

    //duplicate array
    firstNameRes = firstNameArray;
    secondNameRes = secondNameArray;

  

    let i, j
   
    //loop the first name
    for (i = 0; i < firstNameArray.length; i++) {
      
      for (j = 0; j < secondNameArray.length; j++) {
        //pair characters of first name with characters from second name
        if (firstNameArray[i] == secondNameArray[j]) {
          //remove the element from the result array
          firstNameRes.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
    
    //loop the second name
    for (i = 0; i < secondNameArray.length; i++) {
      //pair characters of second name with characters from first name
      for (j = 0; j <firstNameArray.length; j++) {
        //remove the element from the result array
        if (secondNameArray[i] == firstNameArray[j]){
          secondNameRes.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
```

output:
firstName: 'o','h'
secondName: 'j','a','n', 'e'
thanks in advance!

Comment: that happens because when you loop the second name, first name has already been cleared of characters "J" and "N", i.e. you compare "oh" with "jane" .

Comment: perhaps you can have a copy of first array and then in the second loop use that

Comment: @cmgchess suggestion is perfect, you clone firstname before processing it, and in the second loop you compare the clone to the second name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably too advanced, but you can do this using regular expressions, like this:

```
var name1 = ...;
var name2 = ...;

var rx = new RegExp('[' + name2 + ']',"g");

name1 = name1.replace(rx,"");
```

Within regex, the brackets ('[' and ']') turn the string into a collection of characters to match

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to do that:

```js
    var firstName = "john"
    var secondName = "jane"
    
    var reg1 = new RegExp("["+firstName+"]","g")
    var reg2 = new RegExp("["+secondName+"]","g")
    console.log(firstName.replace(reg2,""))    
    console.log(secondName.replace(reg1,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code was you making the duplicated arrays that incorrectly, you need to copy arrays like that:

```js
var firstName = "john"
    var secondName = "jane"
    firstName = firstName.toLowerCase();
    secondName = secondName.toLowerCase();

    //remove whitespaces and split to array
    var firstNameArray = firstName.replaceAll(" ", "").split('');
    var secondNameArray = secondName.replaceAll(" ", "").split('');

var firstNameRes = [...firstNameArray]; // Here the way we copy the ARRAY elements, it doesn't work like strings.
  var secondNameRes = [...secondNameArray];
  
  // I CHANGED ALL CODE BELOW FOR YOU TO WORK
  let indexToRemoveFirstName = [];
  let indexToRemoveSecondName = [];
    //loop to get indexes
    for (let i = 0; i < firstNameArray.length; i++) {
      
      for (let j = 0; j < secondNameArray.length; j++) {
        //pair characters of first name with characters from second name
        if (firstNameArray[i] == secondNameArray[j]) {
          //storing the indexes to remove from originals arrays
          indexToRemoveFirstName.push(i);
          indexToRemoveSecondName.push(j);
        }
      }
    }
    
    //loops to remove from Array after having the indexes, it needs to loop backwards:
    for (let i = indexToRemoveFirstName.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    firstNameArray.splice(indexToRemoveFirstName[i], 1)
    }
    
    for (let y = indexToRemoveSecondName.length-1; y >= 0;y--){
    secondNameArray.splice(indexToRemoveSecondName[y], 1)
  }
      
      console.log(firstNameArray);
      console.log(secondNameArray);
```

Comment: @GrafiCode I am sorry if I offended you, but my explication stands, he cloned the arrays wrongly that caused his code to work incorrectly, in your comment you said he needs to clone his code, but if you see his code, you will see that he tried to do that, but incorrectly. I edited my code. I did not mean anything by the sentences that I wrote, I deleted that as well.

Comment: I see your edits, thanks for that. I'm going to delete my comment and the downvote.

Comment: @FekiHamza Thanks man! 

Also thank to all of you for answering my question!

Comment: You're welcome, please if you liked my answer, kindly vote it up. Thanks